# Convert date to ccyymmdd using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, xslt

I need to use JavaScript to covert a date to to from `'2012-09-15T00:00:00'` to a CCYYMMDD format? How can I do this?

Comment: What do .NET or XSLT have to do with this?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using the jquery inside of xslt that is being used in a .net application –

Comment: How were we meant to know that from your question, and what difference would you expect it to make to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replace` and `split`.

```
var date = '2012-09-15T00:00:00';
date = date.replace(/-/,"").split("T")[0];// date will be 20120915
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what .NET and XSLT have to do with your question.

You could use the `Date` constructor to parse the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) encoded string into a javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

```
var dateStr = '2012-09-15T00:00:00';
var date = new Date(dateStr);
```

and then build the desired format:

```
var year = '' + date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
var day = '' + date.getDate();
day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
var formattedDate = year + month + day;
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Chsnt/).

Comment: I'm using the jquery inside of xslt that is being used in a .net application

Comment: @darin-dimitrow when trying to use this in xlt i get this error {"Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 410, position 22."}